# Client Side Storage/Caching Large HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I have a web page that references and initializes multiple instances of the same ASP.NET generic user control.

What I want to do, is to cache/store the entire contents (html) of those controls somewhere on the client using the jquery `detach()` method.

The solution of localStorage does not fit here as it has a limit to 5MB which is low for my needs.

For now, i am using a global variable and more specific a javascript array(key-value) to store the data.

What do you think of this solution? Will I notice any lags or performance issues on browser? Is there any limit for that global var?

Also, is there a better way to implement such a task?

Comment: you might want to check browser compatibility before relying just on local storage: http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage

Comment: Thank you Saturnix. Actually i can't rely on local storage at all, since the 5 MB limit is very low for my needs.

Comment: What exactly of the js array implementation don't you like? I think that's the best way to go. Localstorage is meant to store data and retrieve it even days later: I don't think that's what you're trying to do. You need the data in the same session, am I right? Then what's holding you to use js?

Comment: Yes you are right, i need the data in the same session only. My only concern is, what if that js array turns to be too big. Will that cause any performance issues - latencies in the application or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cross browser compatibility, you can try an AJAX call that pulls/increments in your massive data and cache the call (stored as JSON/JSONP). jQuery has a cache mechanism but the meat of the implementation is going to be on the headers of the page call. Specifically you're going to want to add `Expires`, `Last-Modified`, and `Cache-Control` on the pages you AJAX in.

Then you'll want to pull in the data asynchronously and do the appropriate UI manipulation (if needed).

You don't want to store massive data in a single variable since its going to take longer when it goes through the JS process.

**localStorage** is still an edge technology, is implemented differently across vendors, and isn't backwards compatible (although there are JavaScript libs that help mitigate backwards compatibility)

**Cookies** not big enough

**On-Page JSON or JS Variable** You lose abstraction and increase initial page weight (which is going to be unsatisfactory if you're on mobile)

*Whatever implementation you do, I would run some simple benchmark performance tests so you have the metric to backup your code*

Comment: Thank you Matt for your explanation. From what i understand you suggest to pass the JSON data asynchronously to the server side, and cache it there, correct? I had thought of that imlementation as well, but i just wanted to minimize the traffic between client and server. Using the implementation of the one global JS variable i noticed that the browser's process memory consumption at windows task manager didn't increase at all.

Comment: Well it's cached on the browser side. So the initial page load can be cached on the browser, then the async call can be cached on the browser too. They are both HTTP/S calls and both are treated the same. You do an initial 2x calls and a 1x call afterwards that yields greater flexibility and overcome any browser limit on data storage alternatives. So if you have 200 pages, you're gonna cache 200 pages + 1 page (async data). In regards of memory, you'll need a lot more data to see any big change at a browser level but you can observe it under better circumstances in Chrome DevTools.

Comment: Hmmm i see what you mean. I could try that, although it doesn't fit 100% to my application (many different user controls already implemented) and see if it works fine. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This will cause browser lag and multiple issues.  You can pretty much guarantee that a mobile browser isn't going to work in this scenario because no sensible mobile browser is going to let you download and store 5MB+ in the LocalStorage object.  It is [a really bad idea](http://dubsism.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/geico-guy-new.jpg?w=510&h=275) to put 5MB+ of HTML into the DOM of any browser and not expect any kind of performance issue.

If you're not concerned about mobile, then look at [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/).  It allows a greater amount of storage and it persists even after the session is closed.  It is fairly [well supported in recent Chrome and Firefox browsers](http://caniuse.com/indexeddb), but requires IE10 or higher.

Comment: Thank you Tim for your answer. I don't care for mobile app right now but i also care for usage in IE8 that indexedDB is not supported.